# This code stopped working in Safari after iOS 9.3

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, safari

I developed a web based app for mobile data entry about 5 years ago that stopped working properly in Safari after either the **9.3 or 9.3.1 release of iOS**. It may have started earlier, but I know for a fact it still works in **iOS 9.2.1**. It works in Chrome without problem.

The following jsfiddle represents a snippet of the app which isn't working: tapping any of the  objects fails to open the choices.

https://jsfiddle.net/panmqj8a/2/

To run it on an iDevice without seeing the HTML/CSS/JS frames:
https://jsfiddle.net/panmqj8a/2/embedded/result/

There's quite a bit of code there, and I don't want this question to appear too long, but apparently I have to paste some code in this question for it to be considered valid.

**Here is a sample of the code that builds one of the select objects:**

```
var activity_data = [ 
    { "id" : "AD1",
      "name" : "Action 1"
    },
    { "id" : "AD2",
      "name" : "Action 2"
    },
    { "id" : "AD3",
      "name" : "Action 3"
    }
];
$.each(activity_data, function(ind,obj) {
    $('.sel_act').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(obj.id).html(obj.name)
    );
});
```

In the full version of the app, the same thing happens (can't tap any of the  elements) plus other buttons on the screen also become unresponsive.

**For the life of me I can't figure out why the app, and this jsFiddle, works in Safari iOS 9.2.1, but not Safari iOS 9.3.1.**

**Edit - now that fiddle seems to be working intermittently for me. Which is annoying.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW - it turns out window.confirm()s were the problem. Not really documented anywhere, but once I removed all the window.confirm()s and replaced them with momentarily displayed  in DIV (where I didn't really need user input, and thus improving interaction), or a div with a promise for when I did, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue for dropdowns in iOS and safari. Finally i resolved by adding `cursor:pointer` in those particular classes. You can also try this, it may work. 
 In your case classes may be `.sel_hcw` or `.mom_select` try once.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it in my app and unfortunately it didn't work. As I mentioned in my Edit above, the snippet I put into jsfiddle doesn't quite have the same problem as my app does, and it's too difficult to bring all of the app into jsfiddle as it spans multiple pages. So, while adding the cursor:pointer may fix the jsfiddle, I know for a fact it doesn't help my app. Thanks again for taking the time.